# Is there an equivalent of System.Xml.XmlAttribute.Specified in System.Xml.Linq?

Tags: .net, linq-to-xml

I have to re-write a large project that uses classes from the System.Xml-Namespace to use the respective classes from System.Xml.Linq using **.NET-3.5**.

One the functions use the `System.Xml.XmlAttribute.Specified` property to find all attributes that are specified in regard to a DTD.

Is there an equivalent to this property in the System.Xml.Linq-Namespace, and, if not, is there a workaround to get the same information from an `System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute`?

Answer (score 1):

There is the [`GetSchemaInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298635.aspx) extension method, the returned `IXmlSchemaInfo` object has a `IsDefault` property which will be true if the value comes from an XSD used for validation.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Alas I have to deal with DTD, not XSD. The GetSchemaInfo of my XAttribute is null.